# Unable to understand the flow of control in the SQL query involving different columns across different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to improve my SQL and for that I need to understand the flow of control in SQL. I understand the basics but here is one such instance where I am unable to comprehend as to how a column from one table can be used in the where clause of another table in a different query(subquery)?

[This](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-report/problem) is the problem statement.
The query is:

```
SELECT
IF (Grade >= 8, Name, NULL),
Grade,
Marks
FROM
(SELECT
Name,
(SELECT Grade FROM Grades WHERE (Min_Mark <= Marks) AND (Marks <= Max_Mark)) AS Grade,
Marks
FROM Students) As MyStudents
ORDER BY Grade DESC, Name;
```

My doubt is that in the subquery: `(SELECT Grade FROM Grades WHERE (Min_Mark <= Marks) AND (Marks <= Max_Mark))`, how come 'Marks' can be used?

Comment: Please don't make is leave this site to understand the question.

Comment: @P.Salmon I am sorry? Could you rephrase the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is what is referred to as *correlated subquery*, MySQL (and many other RDBMS) allow fields from outer queries to be referenced in subqueries one "layer" deep. One way of looking at is that subqueries can access the scope of the query they are contained within, but not scopes farther out than that.

In multi-table queries, it is considered good practice to qualify all field names with the table (or alias of the table) they are from to make the query easier to read; this is especially important in this case, as it is not obvious in your query's current form that it even has correlation.

On small sets of data from an outer query, especially when the data in the subquery is relatively costly to calculate, a correlated subquery can be faster; but when there is a lot of data from the outer query that must be handled by a correlated subquery, a correlated subquery can become quite costly as correlated subqueries are processed repeatedly (once for each row from the outer query).

Also, care must be taken with subqueries in the SELECT of an outer query. Such subqueries must only return one row.

As a general rule, unless a subquery greatly reduces the number of rows joined, joins are almost always better performing.

Your query does not appear to require any subqueries:

```
SELECT IF(g.Grade >= 8, s.Name, NULL)
   , g.Grade
   , s.Marks
FROM Students AS s
LEFT JOIN Grades AS g ON s.Marks BETWEEN g.Min_Mark AND g.Max_Mark
ORDER BY g.Grade DESC, s.Name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `JOIN` in a query like the following:

```
SELECT IF (Grade >= 8, Name, NULL) AS Name, Grade, Marks
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Students
      LEFT JOIN Grades ON (Min_Mark <= Marks) AND (Marks <= Max_Mark)
      ORDER BY Grade DESC, Name ASC) AS Complete_report;
```

You should also put the `ORDER BY` in the subquery in order to have grades correctly sorted for those students whose name will be hidden by NULL.

What happens in this query is:

1. All the rows from the `Student` table will be retrieved
2. To each of these rows is attached only the rows from the `Grades` table matching the condition
3. Rows are sorted by Grade descending and by name
4. Data is processed again to substitute names with NULL if the grade is less than 8

The main difference between the query I posted and the one in your questions is in the second step. Let's suppose that the Student table has N rows.

In the query using the `LEFT JOIN` all rows from the Student table are joined to all rows from Grades table and filtering only matching rows, performing just 2 of reads handling N*10 rows.
Instead, in the query you proposed, for each row in the Student table is performed a read from the Grades table to retrieve the matching element, performing N+1 reads, handling N rows.

Comment: Yeah but I want to understand the flow of control of the query and the fact that how come 'Marks' can be used in this sub-query. Your answer does not address the aforementioned questions.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'll edit explaining the flow of what happens in this query and why you can't do that in the query you posted.

Comment: thanks
Just for the record, the query that I had posted works well, best, in fact, I wanted to know the flow of control of the query mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava the query you posted may work well now, but it will not scale well with larger amounts of data.

Comment: Added some details explaining also the point @Uuerdo mentioned.